# Android - How to specify photo file name/directory using Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

How can I specify the name and destination of captured photo using Phonegap? Couldn't find this info anywhere. Right now it just goes to /sdcard/pic.jpg.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function capturePhoto() {
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,  
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });  

function onSuccess(imageURI) { 
var image = document.getElementById('myImage'); 
image.style.display = 'block';
image.src = imageURI; 
} 

function onFail(message) { 
alert('Failed because: ' + message); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `content://media/external/images/media/n`

where *n* is the image number you are trying to call (1,2,3, etc)

Comment: I understand that is where it goes by default but I want to specify a different directory and the file name. Any ideas?

Comment: Right now every picture gets written twice. `/sdcard/pic.jpg` (which gets overwritten everytime a picture is taken) And `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1314983423118.jpg` (All pictures taken show up here)... These are the default settings.